# Determine whether $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \sqrt{n} }{n^2+3}$ converges or diverges. - Please check my reasoning.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{ \sqrt{n} }{n^2+3}$ converges or diverges.

I would appreciate it if someone could check my reasoning for this problem and indicate if I have made any mistakes, why they are mistakes, and how to properly reason for the answer.

My reasoning is as follows.

We know that $ 0 > \dfrac{ \sqrt{n} }{n^2+3} > \dfrac{1}{n^2} $.

We also know that $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ diverges by the p-series test, since $p=2>1$.

Therefore, since $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ diverges, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{ \sqrt{n} }{n^2+3}$ also must diverge, since $0 >\dfrac{ \sqrt{n} }{n^2+3} > \dfrac{1}{n^2}$.

Thank you.

Comment: "We also know that $\frac{1}{n^2}$ diverges by the p-series test, since $p=2>1$." Somebody should check their notes (and their understanding of the subject).

Comment: @Did Indeed. I seem to have confused myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may observe that, for $n>1$,
$$
0<\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2+3} < \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}
$$ since  $\displaystyle \sum\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ is *convergent* then the initial series $\displaystyle \sum\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2+3} $ is *convergent* by the comparison test.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ actually converges by the $p$-test. A famous result by Euler shows that it is actually $\pi^2 / 6$.

In order to use the comparison test, we need to show that the terms in our sequence $(a_n)$ are *smaller* than the terms of a sequence $(b_n)$ where $\sum b_n$ converges. What you have shown is that the terms in your sequence are *larger* than the terms of a sequence with a convergent series.

Comment: You're right! I seemed to have gotten it the wrong way around!